# Redirect a programm audio stream to skype as microphone output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype

I wanted to ask if its possible to stream the output only from Chrome or other programm to skype using pulseaudio. If I choose the monitor of my playback device, the skype user hears himself, because his talking is also coming to my playback device which I redirect to skype from the recording tab.
If I play a video on Chrome for example, how can I stream the audio output to the skype user without him hearing himself? (I would like to hear the audio from youtube too)

Edit: I forgot to mention that I also want to mix in the input from my microphone (I am using one via usb) so that I can talk while playing Chrome videos

Edit #2: I achieved redirecting the output to skype, but now I cannot hear the song myself:

[image]

Comment: Solution of your problem is very similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/388675/1001338) . And you have to use the newly created entry in front of Skype in the pavucontrol window , and then select that entry also in the recording tab. I tried a similar scenario myself and that worked.

Comment: Yes I've read this one. It is not explained what pactl does and what the attributes mean, but I will try it

Comment: It generates a new source in the pulseaudio which you can use to redirect the output sound of Chrome to it and at the same time recording it via Skype . The previous sources (builtin and monitor of builtin) are still there.

Comment: I updated the question, now I cannot hear chrome myself, though the other person on skype hears it. Is it possible that we both hear it?

Comment: Check the volume of "Remapped Built-in audio" and "Monitor of Remapped Built-in audio" in "Output Devices" and "Input Devices" respectively.

Comment: I think you've accidentally run the command " pactl load-module module-null-sink" which makes the new source quiet.

Comment: Yeah actually the new sink is quiet as I was looking from here - http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php/topic,119695.msg905379.html#msg905379 

I created virtual sink