Discord screen sharing problem
I have a problem with the broadcast screen in discord, when I turn it on then the person watching the stream does not hear the sound at all (the problem with the display of the stream itself has already been fixed by switching to x11). I tried a program for sound but nothing happens, please help.

Does this answer solve your problem?
https://askubuntu.com/a/388675

You may want to ask this on a Discord support site.
